# Unable to read window.sessionStorage.getItem('anyproperty') using typescript in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, session-storage

I started a project in `react` with `javascript` and it worked fine. Now when I migrated it to `typescript`, the only problem is that I am not able to read values from

```
window.sessionStorage.getItem('anyproperty')
```

This works fine in JS.

Comment: Does it actually not work or are you just getting type errors?

Comment: It’s giving me null

Comment: And are you sure that the value is stored? Why don't you try executing that sentence in the browser's console, to see if there is such a property?

Comment: Sorry Guys this was a time waste question for all of you. I read through my code and found out that I have done a typo :(